only main branch shows up for a new pipeline running off a feature branch
I've setup a pipeline that takes input from user to allow them to chose one or more services as a tick box and is currently running from a feature branch.
All is working fine but my issue is that when I run this pipeline it can only see the main branch not the release or other feature branches of the repo.
Could someone advise why i don't see other branches when running the pipeline? I'm specifying the branch name under "resources" though (See the code below). I don't want users to manually enter the release branch or feature branch name every time they run this pipeline.
below is the code for my pipeline
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
# hyphens not supported in the name
- name: external_portal
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: internal_portal
  type: boolean
  default: false

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: deploy-templates/deploy-templates
      ref: refs/heads/feature-branch
    - repository: external-portal
      type: git
      name: aks-microservices/ExternalPortal
      ref: refs/heads/main
    - repository: internal-portal
      type: git
      name: aks-microservices/InternalPortal
      ref: refs/heads/main
      
stages:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.external_portal, true) }}:
    - template: pipelines/templates/deploy.yml@templates
      parameters:
        aksNameSpace: 'external'
        aksServiceName: 'external-portal'
- ${{ if eq(parameters.internal_portal, true) }}:
    - template: pipelines/templates/deploy.yml@templates
      parameters:
        aksNameSpace: 'internal'
        aksServiceName: 'internal-portal'


for security i have changed my code and removed parameters etc
I was hoping to see all branches of the repo



FYI repository: external-portal is duplicated in the resources section.

I'm still trying to understand what your problem is. What exactly do you mean by "...why i don't see other branches when running the pipeline"? See branches where exactly?

@RuiJarimba I have corrected the typo. pipeline works fine. Its only that i shared edited version for security

@RuiJarimba I have added picture in my main body to explain what i mean by not seeing other branches. Sorry cant do a detailed dig but it should explain the problem. In this particular pipeline i can only see main branch but if i run other pipelines i see 10s of branches

See my answer below.

@RuiJarimba i think adding image confused it further. Please see the second image "pipeline wtih correct branch selected. When i run this pipeline and select correct feature branch where this yaml file lives. It presents me with correct options for the services to pick from. but issue is that i only see this feature branch and main branch and not others."Encontered error(s): Could not find valid pipeline for this branch/tag" is not an issue

Sorry but I'm definitely confused :-) What branches are you expecting to see there? Please note that you will only see branches from the repository where the YAML pipeline file is located. In other words, you won't see branches from other repositories defined in resources.

@RuiJarimba you probably answered the question. my yaml file for the pipeline lives in a feature branch and it doesnt exist in other branches that i expected to see. it will take me sometime to merge my feature branch with this yaml file to main and test. Thanks

Please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer.


Encontered error(s): Could not find valid pipeline for this branch/tag

In order to use the pipeline with other branches, ensure that your pipeline YAML file (e.g. azure-pipelines.yml) and related YAML templates exist in the branch you are trying to use.
